# How to create a list of strings using a special char to understand where to split

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that consist of the songs from all the albums of pink floyd, which looks like that:

```
#The Piper At The Gates Of Dawn::1967
*Lucifer Sam::Syd Barrett::03:07::Lucifer Sam, Siam cat
Always sitting by your side
Always by your side
... ( The lyrics of the song )
*Matilda mother::Syd Barrett::03:07::There was a king who ruled the land
His majesty was in command
With silver eyes the scarlet eagle
... ( The lyrics of the song )
#Another album
*another song
song's lyrics
```

I would like to create a list of strings out of it, using the albums ( indicated using # ) as one string, and all the songs in it as another string after that and so on, like this:

```
["album\n", "*song's name\nlyrics\n*song's name\nlyrics ..."]
```

Thanks a lot! :D

Edit: so I noticed that my explanation is a bit clumsy, So i will rephrase it.

What i want to do is to convert the given text into a list, which has each album and it's data in separated variables, so i would have something like that:

```
["album's name, "(Everything between the album's name and the next one)", "album's name", ...]
```

and so on.

The albums have # before them, and i need to use it somehow to separate it from it's songs.

I tried to do a for which finds each # and the first \n after that to create the list, but it went into ashes :(

IMPORTANT! CLEAR EXPLANATION: consider you have a string that looks like that:

```
#Hello
Whatever
#Hello
More Whatever
```

I want to separate each #Hello with it's Whatever. so i would have something like that:

```
["hello", "Whatever", "Hello", "Whatever]
```

I'm really sorry for my bad explanation abilities. this is the easiest way i can think of to explain it to you :D

Comment: show your initial efforts

Comment: Cant understand can you make  more clear with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not super efficient, but works:

```
f = "filepath"

txt = "".join([line + "#" if line.startswith("#") else line for line in open(f)])
data = [x for x in txt.split("#")][1:]
data

['The Piper At The Gates Of Dawn::1967\n',
 '*Lucifer Sam::Syd Barrett::03:07::Lucifer Sam, Siam cat\nAlways sitting by your side\nAlways by your side\n... ( The lyrics of the song )\n*Matilda mother::Syd Barrett::03:07::There was a king who ruled the land\nHis majesty was in command\nWith silver eyes the scarlet eagle\n... ( The lyrics of the song )\n',
 'Another album\n',
 "*another song\nsong's lyrics\n"]
```

Comment: Wow, It worked! I bless you my friend. I would just like to know how it works if you dont care of course :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using regular expressions (`re` module), consider following example, lets say that you have file `songs.txt` as follows:

```
#Song 1
First line
Second line
#Song 2
First line of second
Last line
```

You could do:

```
import re
with open('songs.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
songs = re.findall(r'(#.+?\n)([^#]+)',data)
#now songs is list of 2-tuples with song name and "song body"
songs = list(sum(songs,())) #here I am doing so called flattening
print(songs) #['#Song 1\n', 'First line\nSecond line\n', '#Song 2\n', 'First line of second\nLast line\n']
```

`pattern` (1st argument of `re.findall`) contains two groups denoted by brackets (`()`), first is for title and second for lyrics. First group need to be in form of: `#` followed by 1 or more not newlines (`\n`) and ending in newline (`\n`). Second group mean simply 1 or more characters which are not `#`.

Comment: That's a really nice approach as well! thanks a lot :D